# JS nextElementSibling выбрать блок через элемент, а не по порядку

Tags: javascript, html

Появился вопрос, связанный с использованием **nextSibling** в ванильном JS.
Есть ли метод для выбора не последующего элемента, а за последующим? То есть через один, а не по порядку.
Например, вот есть код, который мне нужен, где реализован аккордеон:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GKB7YF8X9N8U

Но между блоками button и div если разместить, например, блок абзаца `<p>`, то скрипт работать не будет, как надо, и необходимо выбирать через один, чтобы попадало на элемент с классом **panel**. Если убрать блоки абзацев, аккордеон заработает, как положено.
Помогите понять, как в этом случае осуществить выборку элементов с классом **panel**?

Comment: @UModeL Тут был бы уместен мем "А что , так можно было???". Спасибо!